# Include pdfsign.js in Node project

Tags: angular, typescript

it is possible to include [pdfsign.js](https://github.com/Communication-Systems-Group/pdfsign.js) in an Angular app (typescript). How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Thanks Amaya San i did this:
Add signpdf and dependencies to angular-cli.json:

```
"scripts": [
    "assets/js/pdfsign/build/lib/forge-patched.js",
    "assets/js/pdfsign/build/lib/pdfjs.parser.js",
    "assets/js/pdfsign/build/pdfsign.js"
],
```

And add this to my service:

```
declare var PDFSIGN: any;
```

But now when i try to sign a PDF i have this error:

```
XRefParseException {message: undefined}
```

I try to sign the pdf in this way:

```
let readerP12Reader = new FileReader();
    readerP12Reader.onload = ( p12File ) => {
      let p12ArrayBuf = (<FileReader>p12File.target).result; //<-- P12 Array Buffer to pass to PDFSIGN
      this.pdfService.getPdf().subscribe( result => {
        let pdfReader = new FileReader();
        pdfReader.onload = ( pdfFile ) =>{
          let pdfArrayBuf = (<FileReader>pdfFile.target).result; //<-- PDF Array Buffer to pass to PDFSIGN
          console.log(pdfArrayBuf);
          let signPdf = PDFSIGN.signpdf(p12ArrayBuf, pdfArrayBuf, "changeit");//<-- The error is in this point
          console.log(signPdf);
        }
        pdfReader.readAsArrayBuffer(result);

      })
    }
    readerP12Reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.pkcs12File);
  }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you could try declaring it as a global variable by doing it like this

```
declare var PDFSIGN: any;
```

but there is a con here, you won't have any intellisense in your IDE, but still your code will run.